# How to Select xml nodes SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this sql script

```
DECLARE @XmlStr XML 
SET @XmlStr = '<EmployeeID>
<Employee>48f9194f-8d46-e111-8849-0050569445f1</Employee> 
<Employee>7d725561-8d46-e111-8849-0050569445f2</Employee> 
<Employee>7d725562-8d46-e111-8849-0050569445f3</Employee> 
<Employee>7d725563-8d46-e111-8849-0050569445f4</Employee> 
</EmployeeID>' 

(SELECT 
    @XmlStr.value('(/EmployeeID//Employee/node())[1]', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') as IDCode 
    FROM @XmlStr.nodes('//EmployeeID') Tab(Col))
```

but when I run it result is:

```
IDCode

48F9194F-8D46-E111-8849-0050569445F1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I want to select all four guids
how can I achieve this?

my sql server version is 10.0.5500.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
(SELECT 
    Col.value('.', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') as IDCode 
    FROM @XmlStr.nodes('/EmployeeID/Employee') Tab(Col))
```

also : 
try to avoid using `//` in xpath

it is good for some specific cases.